# xamarin forms background serveries

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-service

i have a basic xamarin application which read from clipboard and modify the text then set it again to clipboard. it works fine when user in the application. but when the user hit home button it stops. so i added my method on OnSleep() and enabled background fetch on IOS and Android but it doesn't work on both.

MainPage.cs:

```
private void clipboardCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (clipboardCheckBox.IsChecked)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<string>("1", "clipboardService");
    }
    else
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<string>("0", "clipboardService");
    }
}
```

App.cs:

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "clipboardService", (value) =>
    {
        if (value.Equals("1"))
        {
            Clipboard.ClipboardContentChanged += async (o, e) =>
            {
                var text = await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
                if (text.Contains("@"))
                {
                    await Clipboard.SetTextAsync(text.Trim('@'));
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what do you expect it to do?  If your app is in the background do you expect it to access the clipboard of the active app?

Comment: yes it should be running as long as the checkbox is checked even in the background.

Comment: You could conceivably do this in Android, but I don't think it's possible in iOS.

Comment: @jason we see apps running music in the background i think it is the same logic.

Comment: playing music in the background is a specific use case that they make special APIs for.  Allowing an app to interfere with the normal clipboard operation of another app is completely different.

Comment: why apple have to be like this? that's really sad.

Comment: because if I could do what you're suggesting I could write an app that changes every clipboard item into a malware link, or upload every clipboard item to a server and harvest data without the user knowing